# PDO Query not returning any results, but the query is valid

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Alright, so here's a little bit of information I've already debugged for you guys.

1. The database is connected.
2. The query (When printed using echo) works fine inside of PHPMYADMIN and returns 7 rows.
3. The query (When used with the old mysql_query function works fine)

**I have read that** PDO SQL Does not allow multiple queries at the same time... but isn't this a single query? If not I guess I have to go back to the old version.

Here's the query(Printed from the PHP File using echo).

```
SELECT `Date`, SUM(`Amount`), `Quantity Sold` FROM Transactions WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Which, on PHPMYADMIN Returns this:

```
 Showing rows 0 - 6 (7 total, Query took 0.0004 sec) [Date: 2014-05-26 - 2014-05-13]
```

Here's the code.

```
try {
    $count=0;
    $statement = $SQLConnection->prepare('
        SELECT `Date`, SUM(`Amount`), `Quantity Sold` FROM ' . $SQLConfig["SQL_DATA_TABLE"] . '
        WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
        GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC');
    $statement->execute();

    //echo "<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>";

    foreach($statement as $row) {
        echo "Row: " . $count;
        $count++;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
}
```

I have also tried adding the line:

```
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

and then changing the foreach to

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()){
```

However, it's still not returning any rows.

I had decided to go back to the other system one last time, while keeping the query unedited, and it works perfectly using the following:

```
mysql_select_db($SQLConfig["SQL_DATABASE"])or die("Error: Cannot locate database");
$statement = 'SELECT `Date`, SUM(`Amount`), `Quantity Sold` FROM ' . $SQLConfig["SQL_DATA_TABLE"] . '
    WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
    GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC';
$results = mysql_query($statement);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
```

The same code was tried using SQLi and returned zero results. What the heck :/ I'm trying to convert my project so it's secure and using prepared statements where necessary, but this is making it extremely difficult.

Code using Sqli

```
if($statement = $SQLConnection->prepare('
    SELECT `Date`, SUM(`Amount`), `Quantity Sold` FROM ' . $SQLConfig["SQL_DATA_TABLE"] . '
    WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
    GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC')) 
{
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($result);
    $statement->fetch();
    echo "Row: " .$result;
}
```

As requested, what $SQLConnection is:

```
<?php
    $configuration = include_once 'Configuration.php';

    $PDOConnection = new PDO('mysql:host' .$Configuration["SQL_HOST"]. ';dbname='.$Configuration["SQL_DATABASE"], $configuration["SQL_USERNAME"], $configuration["SQL_PASSWORD"]);  
    $NormalConnection = mysql_connect($Configuration["SQL_HOST"], $Configuration["SQL_USERNAME"], $Configuration["SQL_PASSWORD"]) or die("Error: Failure to connect to host.");
    $SQLiConnection = new mysqli($Configuration["SQL_HOST"], $Configuration["SQL_USERNAME"], $Configuration["SQL_PASSWORD"], $configuration["SQL_DATABASE"]);             

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    }
?>
```

The $SQLConnection is actually a parameter in my code, so depending on which database I'm testing I'll pass $PDOConnection, $NormalConnection, or $SQLiConnection

Example:

```
createIndex($PDOConnection, $Configuration);
```

---

```
function createIndex($SQLConnection, $SQLConfig) {
```

Comment: After `$statement->execute();` add `$statement->fetchAll();`

Comment: Trying it for both SQLi and PDO, I'll post back

Comment: @Daan No changes in output for either. Also, fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) is required for the PDO version

Comment: @ChristianTucker Whats the output of `var_dump($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`?

Comment: @RahilWazir array(0) { }

Comment: Also `print_r($statement->rowCount());` returns 0

Comment: It seems you should show us what exactly is SQLConnection and how is class of this object defined

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek -- It has been added to the bottom on the question.

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct connection? For PDO you added $PDOConnection and in examples earlier you have $SQLConnection that is not defined.

Comment: $SQLConnection <> $PDOConnection OR $NormalConnection OR $SQLiConnection

Comment: @SQLConnection is a parameter, it's being passed. I'm sure, as I've tested all of the connections.